# MySQL Update Ranking and Ties

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Rank  RankTies  TeamName  WinningPercentage
                TeamA     1000
                TeamB     1000
                TeamC     500
                TeamD     250
                TeamE     250
                TeamF     250
                TeamG     0
```

I would like to use a stored routine to rank these by WinningPercentage DESC so the updated table should be:

```
Rank  RankTies  TeamName  WinningPercentage
1     2         TeamA     1000
1     2         TeamB     1000
3     1         TeamC     500
4     3         TeamD     250
4     3         TeamE     250
4     3         TeamF     250
7     1         TeamG     0
```

I can do this with a temp table but is there a more elegant solution, like one UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0f69/1)

`(select * from T) T2` here to avoid MySQL restriction when you can't use updated table in the subquery: (`"You can't specify target table 'T' for update in FROM clause"`)

```
update T T1 set RankTies=(select count(*) from 
                            (select * from T) T2 
                            where T2.WinningPercentage=T1.WinningPercentage),

Rank=(select count(*)+1 from 
                            (select * from T) T2 
                            where T2.WinningPercentage>T1.WinningPercentage)
```

Comment: Wow!  That was very simple and elegant.  Thanks.